# Is the expression `requires { typename enable_if_t<fun_v<T>>; }` the same as `fun_v<T>` "by definition" for any meta-predicate fun_v?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, enable-if, requires-clause

I'm reading Josuttis' C++20 the Complete Guide, and I *think* I've absorbed that a clause like the one in the template below

```cpp
template<typename T>
requires requires { typename std::remove_const_t<T>; }
…
```

is completely useless as it resolves to `requires true` because `remove_const_t` always returns a type when given a type.

However, I reasoned, that's not the case, for instance, for `enable_if`, so I came up with

```cpp
requires { typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>; }
```

Now, since the `requires` expression simply checks that the requirements in the `{…}` are well-formed, I think that's basically what the following does

```cpp
std::is_integral_v<T>
```

It seems pretty uncontroversial to me, but I'm asking because I'm new to C++ concepts and it is perfectly possible that I'm making a mistake.

Comment: Are you asking about the difference between them as constraints with `requires`? Or is there a difference anywhere?

Comment: @康桓瑋, I'm asking if changing `fun_v<T>` to `requires { typename enable_if_t<fun_v<T>>; }` is supposed to generate the same program for any possible `template<class T> inline constexpr bool fun_v = fun<T>::value;`

Comment: What is `T`?  Is it some typedef or template parameter, or might it be a (meta)expression?

Answer (score 0):

The two expressions have the same effect as, in this case, the `requires` is a boolean expression itself.

Specifically, the first expression works as `std::enable_if` is implemented in the following way:

```cpp
template<bool B, class T = void>
struct enable_if {};
 
template<class T>
struct enable_if<true, T> { typedef T type; };
```

When the `fun_v<T>` is true, the template partial-specialization is used, and the requires-expression is satisfied, since it simply verifies whether `type` is well-formed. Likewise, when the `fun_v<T>` is false, the first template is used, and the requires-expression is not satisfied, since `type` is not well-formed.

Comment: Nowhere in my question I've referred to actually using that nonsense. I've just asked if the two expression have precisely the same effect.